# How to write a file that is being read?

Tags: delphi, file-io

My application reads a TextFile of floating point numbers slowly. From time to time circumstances change and the file has to be rewritten. Some example code:

```
procedure TAMI_Column_Selector.read_continuously (file_name: string);
var infile: TextFile;
    f: Double;
begin
   AssignFile (infile, file_name);
   Reset (infile);
   try
      while not EOF (infile) do
      begin
         Read (infile, f);
         process (f); // this may take quite some time, seconds or even minutes
      end; // while
   finally
      CloseFile (infile);
   end; // try..finally
end; // read_continuously //
```

How can I write a file that is open for reading? More specifically:

1. how can I write a file that is open for reading?
2. how to prevent a crash when the application tries to read a file that at that moment
   is being written
3. how does my application know that the file has been rewritten?

I think I could solve the first to questions be reading the file into memory and read that (is there a TextFile that can be written to and read from memory)? Then still remains how I can test a file has been written over.

Anyone having an (elegant) solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Using Delphi XE on windows 7

Comment: Make you reading program robust to incomplete reads. Then use modern IO (i.e. `TFileStream`) rather than Pascal IO. For your writer specify `fmShareDenyWrite` when you open the file. For your reader specify `fmShareDenyNone`. Or, use a database!

Comment: The situation I describe is an import facility, so I use csv-files. A database dsoes solve all problems but is not feasible in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To write to a file that's also open for reading, there's generally not anything special the writer needs to do. If everyone else who has the file open has *allowed* writing to the file, then the intended writer can open the file for writing, write to the file, and close it. If the others *haven't* allowed writing to the file, then the intended writer won't be allowed to open the file in the first place, and there's nothing it can do about it.

How to open a file for reading while also allowing writing depends on the opening method being used. With `CreateFile`, the *dwDesiredAccess* parameter is the usual `GENERIC_READ`, and the *dwShareMode* parameter is `FILE_SHARE_READ or FILE_SHARE_WRITE`. If you're using a `TFileStream`, then the *mode* parameter of the constructor should be `fmOpenWrite or fmShareDenyNone`. If you're using `AssignFile` and `Reset`, then you'd need to set the `FileMode` global variable, but that doesn't support any sharing modes, so you can't use Pascal-style I/O.

Reading a file that is at the same time being written does not inherently cause a crash. It certainly doesn't cause problems at the OS level. If your program crashes, it's because it wasn't written to anticipate reading failures. When you read something, check the API result to confirm that you read as many bytes as you requested. You can also have the reading and writing applications communicate with each other. You might use a synchronization object to serialize access to the file, or the writer might send the reader a signal to indicate that the file has changed, and that the previous read might not be accurate anymore. It's up to you to work the details.

If the reader is going to keep a copy of the file in memory, then it probably doesn't need to bother sharing write access. Instead, it can open the file and only share read access, make a copy of the file in memory, and the close the file. The writer can then open the file without any worries of trampling on the reader process because there's nothing to trample. It can notify the reader that something changed, and the reader can either reload the entire file or just load the part that changed. (The writer will have to tell the reader which part changed, though; there's no other way for the reader to detect that without reading the entire file and seeing how it differs from the memory copy.)

Another way to keep writes from interfering with reads is to use transactions. [Transactional NTFS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb968806.aspx) is being phased out, though. Microsoft has published [a list of alternatives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh802690.aspx), so you can try to find something that matches your needs.

Comment: Thank you very much for this elaborate answer. I think it answers all the pitfalls I should avoid. There is one thing I don't know yet, how do I know that the file has been (re)written?

Comment: I should have phrased question 3 more precisely. What I mean is how I can detect a file being modified by another application. I see paragraph 3 as an explanation of detecting changes within an explanation. If more was intended I am not sure what to do.

Comment: That's been my assumption all along: One or more processes are reading, and one or more others are writing. The sure-fire way for a process to know that another process modified the file is for the other process to *tell* it that it has done so; that's what the second part of my third paragraph is getting at. You can also try using [`ReadDirectoryChangesW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365465.aspx) to detect that files in a directory have changed size or last-write time.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your answer made me change from using TextFiles to Streams. That gives a better control of the mode in which a file is opened. One question about `ReadDirectoryChangesW': when writing a file it fires several times: is there any way to determine which event belongs to the Close event? See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10125444/how-detect-the-correct-modification-of-a-file