# How detect the correct modification of a file?

Tags: delphi, windows-7, file-io, delphi-xe, datemodified

In a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9983060/how-to-write-a-file-that-is-being-read) one of my questions was how my application could know that a file has been rewritten. I should have added: "by another application". First I tried [ShellNotify](http://delphikingdom.torry.net/authorsmore.php?id=6057) which reports changes in a directory but not in a specific file afaik, am I missing something?

Now I use FileAge in a timer that checks each second whether a specific file has changed. While that works it detects *two* modifications, about 13 ms apart; this behavior persists when I change the testing interval to 10 seconds. The code below is the callback of the timer.

```
procedure TAMI_Column_Selector.doWork (Sender: TObject);
var new_stamp: TDateTime;
begin
   if FileAge (remove_extension (FileName) + '.csv', new_stamp) then
   begin
      if (new_stamp <> FDateTimeStamp) then
      begin
         FDateTimeStamp := new_stamp;
         FTask.SyncCall (notify_user);
      end; // if
   end; // if
end; // doWork //
```

My questions:

1. What exactly does cause the `notify_user` to be called twice in the code above? A dumb mistake or some strange behavior of the file system (e.g. the modification date is set on opening and on closing the file)?
2. It feels kind of "wasteful" to check each second whether a file has changed. Is there something like ShellNotify that notifies me only when a specific file has been modified?

**Update**

The answer of David Heffeman (use `ReadDirectoryChangesW` instead of polling) is a correct answer for question 2. However, it leads as well to several calls during one modification (from the users point of view) as mentioned in question 1.

I compared `ReadDirectoryChangesW` and the polling method. Tested with two files (0.5MB and 10 MB). In both cases the polling method was called consistently twice and the `ReadDirectoryChangesW` was called several times (3 to 5 times). I'll revert to the polling method and ignore the first `FileAge` change. I know I cannot be sure that this behavior will be consistent as I don't understand the mechanism causing it.

Comment: [`ReadDirectoryChangesW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365465(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: `remove_extension (FileName) + '.csv'` -> `ChangeFileExt(FileName, '.csv')` (Doesn't solve your problem).

Comment: @DavidHeffeman, Thanks, it seems that FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_ACCESS could do the trick. I'll report back on it.

Comment: @GolezTrol, I'm always glad with tips to do things better or more efficient, so thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is not a direct answer to your question, but I would recommend using [`ReadDirectoryChangesW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365465.aspx) rather than polling.

Comment: It solves one part of my problem: no more polling. The other problem alas remains: the event is sent several times. Probably opening, writing and closing the file all send a modification event. As this would cause reading a big file over and over again, that means reading an incomplete file.

Comment: There's probably not a right lot you can do about that. You'd probably need to use IPC to communicate with the app that does the writing so that you know when it has really done.

Comment: That's the problem, I have no control over the application that writes the file. I'll look into the polling method better: when it consistently fires two times I'll return to that method.

Comment: you can need to set properties for dwNotifyFilter.
Otherwise a write to file will fire an event for last write, for last access and for change size. If you set the filter to FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE it should work like intended.

Comment: @Pieter, I set the filter to FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE as the *only* parameter but I still receive 3 messages (open, write, close?). Anyhow, thanks for the explanation, uptill now I was just guessing.